# Perl no localiza el módulo

Tags: perl, packages, cpan

Estoy revisando un módulo en *Perl* (**test.pm**). Estuve llamando dicho módulo desde mi script principal de diferentes maneras:

Con `use`:

```
use "C:/Usuarios/mitico/Documents/test.pm";
```

Con `lib`:

```
use lib "C:/Usuarios/mitico/Documents/test.pm";
use test.pm;
```

Estuve empleando varias maneras de utilizar mi módulo pero nunca lo ubica.

¿Cómo se usa un módulo_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **lib** hay que indicarle la ruta completa o una relativa desde el sitio en donde se encuentra el programa que va a usar el módulo.

Así, suponiendo que el módulo **miModulo.pm** está en "C:\Usuarios\mitico\Documents\miModulo\lib":

```perl
use lib 'C:/Usuarios/mitico/Documents/miModulo/lib';
```

o así, suponiendo que el programa está en "C:\Usuarios\mitico\Documents":

```perl
use lib 'miModulo/lib';
```

Haz la prueba:

```sh
$ cd C:/Usuarios/mitico/Documents
$ perl -E "use lib 'miModulo/lib'; use miModulo; 1"
```

Si no sale ningún error, es que sí encuentra el módulo **miModulo.pm**

Más información ejecutando **perldoc lib** y en el foro de Perl en Español.

P.D.: Observa que en los Windows modernos se pueden usar barras diagonales iguales a las de Unix.

Comment: Ya me funciono, cuestion de directorios, gracias!

Comment: @MiticoMancipe ¿Podrías aclarar qué cambiaste para que te funcione?

Comment: Era un error de directorio, seguí las sugerencias y la documentación propuesta por Joaquin.